# Object hide and show at scroll

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I already have a function which works well : when i scroll the page, the object show up (opacity) and slides 80px (top -/+80px) when half of it enters at the bottom or top of the window and when it leaves it slides again and becomes hidden.

The code

```
function visibleHide(){
    $('.hideme').each(function(){
        var half_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()/2);
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();              
        if(half_of_object < top_of_window) {
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'-80px'});
        }
        if (half_of_object > bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'80px'});
        }   
        else if(half_of_object > top_of_window && half_of_object < bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'1','top':'0'});
        }
    });
}
visibleHide();
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    visibleHide();
});
```

Now i have objects which are longer than the height of the window, so i would like them to do the same effects when the object bottom arrives 10vh before the window top and the object top is 10 vh before the window bottom.

I tried something like that but it does not work at all, what is wrong ?

```
function visibleHide(){
    $('.hideme').each(function(){
        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()-'10vh');
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()+'10vh');
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();              
        if(bottom_of_object < top_of_window) {
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'-80px'});
        }
        if (top_of_object > bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'80px'});
        }   
        else if(bottom_of_object > top_of_window && top_of_object < bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'1','top':'0'});
        }
    });
}
visibleHide();
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    visibleHide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in those 2 lines

```
var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()-'10vh');
var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()+'10vh');
```

The **outerHeight()** function returns a number, and you are just trying to decrease/increase it from a string.

You should calculate 1vh point like this

```
var windowOneViewHeight = $(window).height() / 100;
```

And then you just multiply it by 10

```
        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()- (windowOneViewHeight * 10));
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()+ (windowOneViewHeight * 10));
```

**Final code**

```
function visibleHide(){
    $('.hideme').each(function(){
          var windowOneViewHeight = $(window).height() / 100;
        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() - (windowOneViewHeight * 10));
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() + (windowOneViewHeight * 10));
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();              
        if(bottom_of_object < top_of_window) {
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'-80px'});
        }
        if (top_of_object > bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'80px'});
        }   
        else if(bottom_of_object > top_of_window && top_of_object < bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'1','top':'0'});
        }
    });
}
visibleHide();
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    visibleHide();
});
```

**Fixes so the element will be hidden correctly:**

```
function visibleHide(){

    $('.hideme').each(function(){
        var windowOneViewHeight = $(window).height() / 100;
        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ( (windowOneViewHeight * 10)); // no also add the item height, only the offset top is needed
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() - (windowOneViewHeight * 10));
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();  



        if(bottom_of_object < top_of_window) {

            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'-80px'});
        }
        else if (top_of_object > bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'0','top':'80px'});
        }   
        else if(bottom_of_object > top_of_window && top_of_object < bottom_of_window){
            $(this).css({'opacity':'1','top':'0'});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: we are approaching but not arrived yet... :) now when my objects go up, they won't be hidden when their bottom arrives 10 vh before screen top and they become hidden much before their top arrives 10 vh before screen bottom. To understand better, i would need : the objects are visible in the middle of the screen 90 vh... they start to be hidden when they have only 10 vh visibility on the screen (bottom screen or top)... draw for better understanding here : www.westhungary.com/hideme.jpg.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, i accepted your answer ! Can you just tell me the following please : it is in a hidden div and when i load the div, the objects have zero opacity, page visitor must start to scroll to see the objects...

Comment: Glad to help :). You can solve your issue in 2 ways, you can remove the call to the function 'visibleHide();' when the page loads, or you can add an if statment inside the function that will check if the $(window).scrollTop() equals to 0. one of those should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot for the ideas ! However i did in a third way : i deleted the "hideme" class in the html and i add it to the div only when i click to the button to show the page. Also i remove the class when i hide the page...